# Are mobile phone calls cached by the network?

Tags: network, mobile

While transmitting a phone call from one mobile phone to another across several carriers, I assume it may be necessary to buffer the audio data for a few seconds.

My questions:

- a) Is it true, that the contents are cached by the provider for very
  short periods of time or are missing frames just being dropped?
- b) If
  they are cached, how long is this information stored and where?

**Why I ask this**: Today, I made a call from one european country to another and I got a replay of what was said on the phone about five minutes ago. This means, the call was established for about 8 minutes when suddenly I heard what the person I called said five minutes ago. It was clearly a recording, as even the background noises where distinctly the same. I listened for about 30 seconds before I hung up. The person I spoke to was unable to hear a thing from what I said during this replay. I know that there are at least three different providers involved: the provider that provides the local network where I currently stay and two providers from the country the two contracts are made in. My provider denies that any recording is happening (no surprise) - not even temporary. I know that this is anecdotal evidence, but it made me curious.

Comment: How is this question related to *security*?

Comment: eluskemi - This question is not a security question. It sounds like someone was recording it - not sure how you'd find out who.